# How to create a custom tabs intent builder action button that saves the current URL

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

I'm trying to add a save feature, and I'd like to get get current URL of the `customTabsIntent`.

```
CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
PendingIntent pendingIntent;
Intent intent = new Intent();
//something
CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
customTabsIntent.launchUrl(context,Uri.parse(URL));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a broadcast receiver like this:

```
public class CustomTabsBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = CustomTabsBroadcastReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Uri uri = intent.getData();
        if (uri != null) {
            ClipboardManager clipboardManager = (ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            String label = "Current url";
            ClipData clipData = ClipData.newUri(null, label, uri);
            assert clipboardManager != null;
            clipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(clipData);

        }

    }
}
```

Register the receiver in the manifest:

```
<receiver
        android:name=".CustomTabsBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true" />
```

Get the link in a pending intent and do what you want with it:

```
Intent copyIntent = new Intent(mContext, CustomTabsBroadcastReceiver.class);
    String label = "Copy link";
    PendingIntent copyPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext,
            COPY_LINK_REQUEST_CODE, copyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mCustomTabsBuilder.addMenuItem(label, copyPendingIntent);
```